# Get all values of array elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array with HTML elements from a selector. Looks like this:

```
var selection = $('.features_items');
// selection = [div.features_item, div.features_item];
```

The div looks like this:

```
<div class="features_item selected" value="2">
```

Now I want to get all values from the div's in the array: [2,3]

Comment: Technically, `selection` isn't an array -- it's an array-like jQuery object. This is only significant if you try to use methods like `shift` or `pop`, which won't work on jQuery objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`jQuery.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) to map the jQuery object to an array in a single step:

```
var values = $.map(selection, function() {
    return $(this).val();
}); // values is now an array equal in length to 'selection'
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

```
var values = [];
$('.features_items').each(function()
{
  values.push( this.getAttribute('value') );
});
alert(values);
```